# gssapi error - when using webhdfs in fluentd

Tags: fluentd, gssapi, webhdfs

As part of our centralised logging, I am sending fluentd output to HDFS (which is Kerberised) using webhdfs plugin. I am getting gssapi library not found error

This is how my td-config output section looks like

```
# Output 
<match docker.*> 
  type copy 
  <store> 
    @type file 
    path /test/ 
  </store> 
  <store> 
    @type webhdfs 
    host  192.168.12.30 
    port  50070 
    path  /logs/es_cluster/access.log.%Y%m%d_%H.#{Socket.gethostname}.log 
    kerberos true 
    kerberos_keytab /etc/security/fluentd-user.headless.keytab 
  </store> 
</match>
```

I am getting following error

```
2018-06-05 11:28:41 +0000 [error]: #0 cannot load such file -- gssapi     path="gssapi" error_class=LoadError error="cannot load such file -- gssapi"
  2018-06-05 11:28:41 +0000 [error]: #0 suppressed same stacktrace
2018-06-05 11:28:41 +0000 [info]: Worker 0 finished unexpectedly with status 2
2018-06-05 11:28:41 +0000 [info]: Received graceful stop
(END)
```

I did tried with
gem install gssapi
on the vm but no success.

Please help.

Thanks in advance
Mujeeb

Comment: sudo yum install gcc
    /usr/sbin/td-agent-gem install gssapi

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo yum install gcc
/usr/sbin/td-agent-gem install gssapi
```

Worked for me.